# Is there a faster way to switch a MediaPlayer's datasource?

Tags: android, media-player, datasource

I am new to Android development, so I am reaching out to see if there is a more efficient, or faster way to switch a MediaPlayer datasource with an onTouch method. I'm trying to create a instrument that will play like a flute, but the audio source wont switch fast enough when I press (touch) the buttons.

I am using the `playNote()` method to switch between the audio files. Any advice is appreciated.

```
public class PlayAggeion extends Activity {

ImageButton patC1;
int soundIsOn = 1;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_aggeion);
    onConfigurationChanged(null);
    addListenerPatima();
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    playNote(R.raw.aa);
}

public void addListenerPatima() {
    patC1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.patC1);
    patC1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                playNote(R.raw.bb);
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                playNote(R.raw.aa);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };

    });
}

public void  playNote(int note){
    // Play note
    try {
        mp.reset();  
        mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + note));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `SoundPool` instead of `MediaPlayer`. `SoundPool` lets you preload a number of sound files and lets you play them one after another without any additional delay. It is often used in games and sound board apps, so it seems to perfectly match your needs.

More info: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Nice tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html#tutorial_soundpool